# How to find correct time difference between 2 arrays of data

Tags: python, time

Hey I am trying to find the difference in 2 times that are given in the form [hour, minute, second] how do I do this? The obvoious answer would be

```
time1_array = ['3', '12','4.8']
time2_array = ['5', '8', '34.87']
time1, time2 = int(''.join(time1_array)), int(''.join(time2_array))
final_time = time2 - time1
```

But I know there are a lot of cases where this will not work and will actually give negative numbers. So what is the correct algorithm to always get the time in a positive correct format?

Comment: Use `abs()` function?

Comment: is that am or pm? What decides that?

Comment: `(hour * 60 + minute) * 60 + second`

Comment: Do you actually want the difference in seconds?

Answer (score 4):

The best method is to convert the list into a `datetime` object, it would help you in making cleaner and efficient code. To create `datetime` object we need a `string` representing a particular time format, as your list had only `integers` , so first we convert it to `string` using the `map(str, lst)` method, then we join the given list elements with a separator `"-"` to distinguish between hour, minutes and seconds, Now we need to apply, `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method., which takes 2 arguments: The format of data and String data, You can see various formats  of data [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
import datetime

time1_array = [3, 12,4.8]
time2_array = [5, 8, 34.87]

time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("-".join(map(str, time1_array)), "%H-%M-%S.%f")
time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("-".join(map(str, time2_array)), "%H-%M-%S.%f")

print time2-time1
>>> 1:56:30.070000
```

Comment: I am actually using datetime, I just wanted to give a rough example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in `datetime` module.

```
def convert_to_datetime(lst):
    return datetime.now().replace(hour=lst[0], minute=lst[1], second=int(lst[2]))
from datetime import datetime
time1_array = [3, 12,4.8]
time2_array = [5, 8, 34.87]
print convert_to_datetime(time2_array) - convert_to_datetime(time1_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well..

```
from datetime import datetime
time1_array = [3, 12,4.8]
time2_array = [5, 8, 34.87]
s1 = ':'.join([str(x) for x in time1_array])
s2 = ':'.join([str(x) for x in time2_array])
FMT = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
print tdelta
```

#### Prints

```
1:56:30.070000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you presented the data as a list of strings and you asked for this: *"difference in 2 times that are given in the form [hour, minute, second] "*
just for fun, I did this without the `datetime`.

So the output is a list of strings, but it's actually the difference in the form, as you requested, *[hour, minute, second]*

The output:

```
['1', '56', '30.07']
```

The code:

```
time1_array = ['3', '12','4.8']
time1_array = map(float, time1_array)
time2_array = ['5', '8', '34.87']
time2_array = map(float, time2_array)

x = time1_array[0]*60*60 + time1_array[1]*60 + time1_array[2]
y = time2_array[0]*60*60 + time2_array[1]*60 + time2_array[2]
if x > y:
    final_time=x-y
elif y >x:
    final_time=y-x
else:
    final_time==0
final_time_hms = []
final_time_h = int(final_time/60)/60
final_time_hms.append(final_time_h)
final_time_m = int(final_time/60)%60
final_time_hms.append(final_time_m)
final_time_s = ((final_time/60)%60 - final_time_m ) *60
final_time_hms.append(final_time_s)
final_time_hms = map(str,final_time_hms)
print final_time_hms
```